# How to compare a value and then return that value instead of 0 or 1?

Tags: mathematics, shader-nodes

I have this node setup here:

[image]

And for all values greater than .5, return that value down there. For all values less than .5, return those values up there. Instead, these nodes either output 0 or 1. Is there a way to output the input value instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something base on this setup:

[image]

Each multiply node will return either 0 or the R value. Then if you add their results that gives you R back.

Or this one:

[image]

Get 0.5 if R is bigger else R. Or get 0.5 if R is smaller else R.

Comment: Thanks. Would something like this work too? https://imgur.com/OJNWJJ0

Comment: Yes that can give you a smooth comparison. Also you can have a look to smooth minimum or smooth maximum.